# How do we shorten sitename in the Google search result breadcrumb?

Tags: blogger, google-search, breadcrumbs, google-rich-snippets

[image]

In the screenshot, 
Expected result - Result 1
Obtained result - Result 2

In the Breadcrumbs, we're requested to provide "home" in the place of  site name. I'm not getting the expected result. Even if I provide "MY-SITE-NAME" in the place of site name, I'm not getting the result I expect.

Do we need to include separate rich Snippets or similar for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

For showing the site name (instead of the site domain) in the first position, Google offers another rich result: [Your Site Name in Results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename)

Current guidelines:

> - Provided names must be reasonably similar to your domain name.
> - Use natural names to refer to the site, such as Google, rather than Google, Inc.
> - The name must be unique to your site — not used by any other site.
> - Not a misleading description of your site.

So it can’t be "Home". If Google would replace the first entry with "Home", Google Search users would no longer be able to see (in this green line) the site’s domain/name or alternatively, what the page’s URL is. You can of course still use "Home" in your [breadcrumbs rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs), if you want to provide it as first entry.

Comment: Can you please check the website snippet? I think I have all the necessary items in place. So what should I do now?Should I have a custom domain for this to work? https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=Amprandom.blogspot.com

Comment: @GZone: We can’t know for sure. Even if you meet all guidelines, it’s never guaranteed that Google picks it up. In your case, maybe (just a guess) the site name is not "reasonably similar" to your domain name? "Random Tyms" and "amprandom.blogspot.com" only have "random" in common.